# Text centered with the logo but icon on the left of it

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project that provided me some pictures of the website look : [image: Logo + Location]

As you can see, the logo and the text under are both aligned in the center but the little icon is a bit on the left of the location, how can I do to make it look that way? And also, I want this little icon to not move between my desktop, tablet and smartphone look.

I have tried to use position: absolute, but it's always moving around between desktop and smartphone, it doesn't stay right next to my text. Basically I want this icon to be at the same distance on PC, tablet and phone.

Thanks in advance for all the help you can provide me!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shrikhand&display=swap');
/* Header */

header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    background-color: white;
}
header h1 {
    font-family: 'Shrikhand', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0rem;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

/* Localisation */

.localisation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    height: 2.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 11px 3px -8px #CCC;
}
.localisation p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #4D4D4D;
}
.localisation i {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ec6ba8c4d3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <h1>ohmyfood</h1>
    </header>
<!-- Localisation -->
    <main>
        <div class="localisation">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
            <p>Paris, Belleville</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the styling on the icon, let flex handle the position of the elements. If you want to create extra space between the icon and text, use css `gap` (see example).

Also I added `flex-wrap: nowrap;` so the text wouldn't wrap under the icon when it gets too small

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shrikhand&display=swap');
/* Header */

header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    background-color: white;
}
header h1 {
    font-family: 'Shrikhand', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0rem;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

/* Localisation */

.localisation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    gap: 5px;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    height: 2.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 11px 3px -8px #CCC;
}
.localisation p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #4D4D4D;
}
.localisation i {
   
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ec6ba8c4d3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <h1>ohmyfood</h1>
    </header>
<!-- Localisation -->
    <main>
        <div class="localisation">
            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
            <p>Paris, Belleville</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
    header{text-align: center;}
    /* Localisation */

    .localisation {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: #eaeaea;
        height: 2.5rem;
        align-items: center;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 11px 3px -8px #CCC;
    }
    .localisation p {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 600;
        color: #4D4D4D;
        padding-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
     <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ec6ba8c4d3.js" 
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- Header -->
        <header>
            <h1>ohmyfood</h1>
        </header>
    <!-- Localisation -->
        <main>
            <div class="localisation">
                <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <p>Paris, Belleville</p>
            </div>
         </main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `position: absolute;` from your `.localisation i` style.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `.localization i` style because you have given the left alignment.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shrikhand&display=swap');
/* Header */

header {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 4rem;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    background-color: white;
}
header h1 {
    font-family: 'Shrikhand', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 0rem;
    padding-top: 0.5rem;
}

/* Localisation */

.localisation {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #eaeaea;
    height: 2.5rem;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 11px 3px -8px #CCC;
}
.localisation p {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #4D4D4D;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ec6ba8c4d3.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Header -->
    <header>
        <h1>ohmyfood</h1>
    </header>
<!-- Localisation -->
    <main>
        <div class="localisation">
       <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
            <p> Paris, Belleville</p>
        </div>
```